# Spring Security 5 - Setup AuthenticationManagerResolver for JWT and OpaqueTokens fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to apply Spring Documentation to setup an OAuth 2.0 Resource Server using Spring Security 5.5.1 : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2reourceserver-opaqueandjwt

My configuration class is similar to what is documented by Spring

```java
@Configuration
public class TokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()).oauth2ResourceServer(
                oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(tokenAuthenticationManagerResolver()));
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> tokenAuthenticationManagerResolver() {
        BearerTokenResolver bearerToken = new DefaultBearerTokenResolver();
        JwtAuthenticationProvider jwt = jwt();
        OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider opaqueToken = opaqueToken();

        return request -> {
            if (useJwt(request)) {
                return jwt::authenticate;
            } else {
                return opaqueToken::authenticate;
            }
        };
    }
    

    Boolean useJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization").replaceFirst("Bearer ", "");
        if (JwtChecker.isJwt(token)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I also include an application.yml with the following form :

```yaml
server: 
  port: 8082
  servlet: 
    context-path: /resource-server

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        opaquetoken:
            introspection-uri: https://idp.example.com/introspect
            client-id: introspect-sample
            client-secret: p@ssword
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://idp.example.com
          jwk-set-uri: https://idp.example.com/connect/jwks_uri
```

From my understanding jwt() and opaqueToken() Beans should be available as long as I put those configurations in my application.yml still the application fails to run/compile saying :

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method opaqueToken()
[ERROR]   location: class x.x.x.config.TokenSecurityConfig

cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method jwt()
[ERROR]   location: class x.x.x.config.TokenSecurityConfig
```

The following post seems to state that it should work : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19426

I do not really understand what is wrong, maybe Spring Docs are wrong ? When I am trying to setup only JWT or Opaque Auth without any AuthenticationManagerResolver, the app compiles

I am probably mixing everything …

I also see this example, which is using a different syntax (not using DSL to get jwt and opaqueToken beans : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/9895d01257679d7cb0d20750ad6d97c53d12fde8)